# Difference between DASK dd.DataFrame and dd.core.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I use dask in my project and recently ran into a weird problem - I need differentiate between dask and pandas dataframes in some places so I use the following **if**

```
    import dask.dataframe as dd    
    if isinstance(df, dd.DataFrame):
       #some specific code
```

but it doesn't always work. I investigated the case and turned out the real type of df is dd.core.DataFrame. What's then the difference between them two? Why are they interchangeable in many cases? And how correctly to check the type of dask dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

`dd.DataFrame` is identical to `dd.core.DataFrame`, see the import on this line: https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/dask/dataframe/__init__.py#L5

```
In [20]: dd.DataFrame is dd.core.DataFrame
Out[20]: True
```

Comment: You're totally right. However as I said - although they look identical there's a real case when the specific code from my post above didn't work until I replaced dd.DataFrame with dd.core.DataFrame.

Comment: Perhaps there is something in your code that makes the above not true, so you should include a minimal reproducer, showing imports and how df is made.